# Missing menu items from Mac OS X Android Studio 2.1.2 IDE related to importing sample code

Tags: android, android-studio

From the Mac OS X Android Studio 2.1.2 IDE splash screen, I don't see "Import an Android code sample". From within the IDE when a project is open, I don't see "File"/"New"/"Import sample code"

This is not the case with others that I work with and also the two menu items show-up in my Windows 10 Android Studio 2.1.2 IDE install.